# QEMU/KVM: Access (host) localhost:4892 from Linux guest

Tags: networking, routes, virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

I use libvirtd with the virt-manager GUI to manage my QEMU/KVM linux guests. I was able to create a bridge device, virbr0, on my host machine (x86_64, Gentoo Linux, no systemd). I connected my VMs to this bridge, as well as a network interface of my host, so guests can access the internet through that. I am not sure if this is the right way to do it, but with this setup it is not possible to access the host's localhost.

I have a webserver running on my host on localhost:4892. I would like to be able to access this local webserver from my VMs. How can I do this?

I understand that https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking suggests that I use a tap device. What confuses me is that virt-manager explicitly warns that a macvtap device is not suitable for a guest-to-host connection. I am not sure if I have to select "bridge" or "Virtual network" in virt-manager. To be honest I have not fully understood what a TAP really is. On my host, I use nftables if this is of any relevance.

Ideally, I would like to be able to decide for each VM if I want it connected to the internet and/or connected to the host:4892.

Thank you for any hints in the right direction.